# Clarification about RNN encoder-decoder equation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

In the paper by [Cho et.al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1078.pdf), section 2.3 details the equations for the modified LSTM cell in RNN used in the paper's implementation. The equation in question is :

[image]

Here, the output of the reset gate (**r**) is element wise multiplied with the previous hidden state **h**<sub><*t*-1></sub>, and then matrix multiplied with the **U** matrix.

Later on, in the Appendix section **A.1.1** explains the equations for the decoder, specifically:

[image]

My question: Is the *r '<sub>j</sub>* element-wise multiplied to the corresponding expression or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{r}$ is a vector; $r'_j$ is a scalar; so this is multiplying a scalar ($r'_j$) by a vector (the part in $[...]$).  There is only one way to multiply a scalar by a vector: you multiply each coordinate of the vector by the scalar.